# Fixed node size in Netgraph

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling, netgraph

I use `Netgraph` (`EditableGraph`) to represent networks. However, when the window is scaled, the nodes become disproportionately large compared to the labels, which remain the same size.   This results in an unappealing visual representation.

How to keep the size of nodes invariant in Python, i.e. insensitive to the window size scaling ?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: In netgraph, node sizes are invariant in data coordinates, such that their extents can be accounted for when computing node layouts and/or the edge routing to prevent node/node or node/edge overlaps. Hence changing the zoom should increase the size of the nodes in display coordinates, so this is the expected behavior. However, netgraph should also re-scale the node labels with every zoom event, so the label size/node size mismatch is unexpected behaviour, and worth looking into. If you raise an issue on the netgraph issue tracker, I won't forget to look into it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have checked again the labels do not scale and remain with the same size.